# Angular 2 Pipe Filter for rendering Array

Tags: angular

I Have problem for rendering the items in the array using search pipe this is my app.module:

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';    
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {CombBox} from "./ComboBox/ComboBox.component";
import {SortPipe} from "./ComboBox/Sort.pipe";
import {SearchPipe} from "./ComboBox/Filter.pipe";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,  FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ,CombBox ,SortPipe,SearchPipe],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And This is my Search Pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from "../hero";
@Pipe({
  name : 'searchPipe',
  pure:false
})

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<Hero>, letter: string): any {
    return items.filter(item => item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(letter)>-1);
  }
   }
```

and this is my Html View

```
<div class="InputHolder">
  <input type="text" class="Input-text" (keyup)="checkkey($event)"  (keyup.enter)="AddHero(Inputtxt.value)" (focus)="OnfocusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()"  #Inputtxt/>
</div>
<div class="UlHolder">
  <ul class="heroes" id="hello" *ngIf="IsVisable"  >
    <li  *ngFor="let hero of heroes | sort |searchPipe: Inputtxt.value">
      {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I Cannot access the data of the array of heroes that i created and show the selected item of search because when i just enter the search pipe all data in the view of the list is disappeared

Comment: Try to insert as first line to `transform()` if(!items || !letter) return;`

Comment: What is `Inputtxt`?

Comment: Actually i found the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from "../hero";
@Pipe({
  name : 'searchPipe',
  pure:false
})

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<Hero>, letter: string): any {
    return items.filter(item => item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(letter.toUpperCase())>-1);
```